# Android Development: Fetch Task (or Reminders) from Google Calendar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-calendar-api

I am fiddling around with java and Android Studio.
I managed to read from the Google Calendar, fetching Events using the ContentResolver from Google - all fine.

```
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
            CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{"title", "dtstart", "dtend"},
            "( dtstart >" + startFrom.getTimeInMillis()
                    + " and dtend <" + endAt.getTimeInMillis()
                    + " and deleted != 1 )",
            null,
            "dtstart ASC"
    );
```

Now I am trying the fetch Tasks as well, from the Google Calendar. When you're adding a new item to your calendar, instead of Events, you can also create "Tasks" (or "Reminders").

[image]

As it seems, there are not stored in the calendar directly(?)

How can I fetch these Tasks (or Reminders) that were created using the calendar app, within my software?

PS: In case of reminders, not talking about reminders for an event here. But about reminders that stand for themselves, independent of an event.